# Conditional Formatting Google Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

I received 4 different purchase orders, with a random purchase order number on it. 
I populate the purchase order number in column A only.

For this example I received the 4 different purchase purchase orders listed below.

Purchase Order 697533 - 2 Items
Purchase Order 697549 - 3 Items
Purchase Order 697564 - 1 Items
Purchase Order 697565 - 2 Items

I would like to highlight all the rows that have a purchase order of "697533" in blue.

In purchase order 697549, I would like to highlight all the rows that has a PO # of  697549 in white.

Then in purchase order 697564 I would like to highlight all the items back in blue.

Finally in purchase order 697565 I would like to highlight all the items back in white.

I would like to continue switching between matching purchase order numbers with the colors alternating.

How can I apply this to the spread sheets ?

[image: Please see the screenshot of this situation]

Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this as the custom formula:

```
=MOD(COUNTUNIQUE($A$2:$A2),2)
```

Comment: Nice Cameron! Thank you SO much this is amazing! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try a CFR based on this custom formula,

```
=isodd(rank($A2, unique($A$2:$A), 1))
```

[image]

[Linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULTQPoe20MNwBFXAfUgDN84jb-Cl3S-ex0epjEx2wwk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you very much but its not always odd or even in that order. I might receive a few odd number PO's in a row. :) Thank you though

Comment: The IsOdd is not based on the actualPO number. It is based on the PO number's Rank within the collection of POs.

Comment: Gotca! This kind of works. It works great to start off with then spazzes out after. Why do you think ?

Comment: I suppose that I was assuming an ordered PO collection. If lower number POs were at the bottom of the list, that would foul up the ranking and you should go with the other response where order is not a consideration.

Comment: haha Yes the PO numbers are not numerically increasing. One would assume it did. lol Thank you very much for ALL your help!!!